# Number of occurrences in Python using dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following exercise:

> Text is given in a single line. For each word of the text count the number of its occurrences before it. For simplicity, we assume there are no numbers, punctuation, or special symbols in the input.
> Consecutive words are separated from each other by one or more spaces.

The exercise is asking explicitly to use dictionaries.

Input:

```
the block on the block on the block on the floor
```

Output:

```
0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 0
```

The code so far:

```py
my_words={} 
s = input()
nums_str = s.split()

count=0
for x in nums_str:
  my_words.update({count:0})
  count= count+1
```

```
the block on the block on the block on the floor
{0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0}
```

This prints out a dictionary with a number as index for each words and a zero.

The idea is use use it to record the position of each word before itself.

This is what I do not understand how to record the position of each word before itself.

Comment: I feel like using a list would be an equally (if not better) approach in this case.

Comment: do you want to find the frequency of each character in input?

Comment: You need to use the *word* as a key rather than the *count*

Comment: the exercise ask the occurrence before itself, see the output in the example

Answer (score 4):

A dictionary alone won't do the trick. If you add a list you can gather the current wordcount there.

The idea is to check if the word is in the dictionary. If not then add it and set the value to `0`. If it is there then increase the value by `1`. Then use the current added or updated value.

```
s = 'the block on the block on the block on the floor'

words = {}
counts = []
for word in s.split():
    if word not in words:
        words[word] = 0
    else:
        words[word] += 1
    counts.append(words[word])

print(counts)
```

Result: `[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 0]`

---

If you don't need to gather the output for further tasks you can drop the list and just print the current value.

```
s = 'the block on the block on the block on the floor'
words = {}
for word in s.split():
    if word not in words:
        words[word] = 0
    else:
        words[word] += 1
    print(words[word], end=' ')
```

---

Same approach with a dictionaries `get` method and a default value. (You can see a similar approach in mousetail's answer)

```
words = {}
for word in s.split():
    words[word] = words.get(word, -1) + 1
    print(words[word], end=' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this, you need to get the values of counter after each iteration. Also, to make this code reusable everywhere, you can create a function out of it, as follows:

```
def dynamic_counter(sequence, delimiter=' '):
    word_dict, count_list = {}, []
    for word in sequence.split(delimiter):
        count_list.append(word_dict.get(word, 0))
        word_dict[word] = word_dict.get(word, 0) + 1
    return count_list


sentence = "the block on the block on the block on the floor"
print(*dynamic_counter(sentence))
```

Comment: This example would be even better if you would respect the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for the names of your variables (e.g. `Dynamic_Counter`-> `dynamic_counter`).

Answer (score 0):

Solution with simple dict:

```py
words = input().split()
count = {}
for word in words:
    print(count.get(word, 0), end=" ") # print earlier words
    count[word]=count.get(word, 0) + 1 # increase the counter
```

Comment: you cannot use Counter

Comment: @EmiliaDelizia can you use any imports?

Comment: @Matiiss No, that would count all occurrences not just occurrences before the word

Comment: you can use find() , rfind() and related

Comment: @EmiliaDelizia Removed references to `Counter`

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you **have** to use a dictionary. Without the aid of a dictionary, you can just do this:

```
mystring = 'the block on the block on the block on the floor'
mywords = mystring.split()
outlist = [mywords[:i].count(w) for i, w in enumerate(mywords)]
print(outlist)
```

If you need a dictionary in the format shown in your question then:

```
mystring = 'the block on the block on the block on the floor'
mywords = mystring.split()
mydict = {k: v for k, v in enumerate([mywords[:i].count(w) for i, w in enumerate(mywords)])}
print(mydict)
```

Comment: When the size of list rises, it'll introduce an exponentially high penalty for time complexity due to redundant counting of same elements of list again and again. Hence, Hashing(Dictionaries) help make code highly fast.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @HIMANSHUPANDEY. I can't seem to find your contribution to this question though

Comment: Your added solution also doesn't reduce time complexity as it is still putting an overhead of counting same entities repeatedly. So better go with other answers

Comment: @HIMANSHUPANDEY My answers are functionally correct. The question does not make any allude to performance being critical. And I still can't see your solution

Answer (score 0):

The code is quite simple. The exercise is about learning dictionaries, so it is recommended to use it.

```
words = input().split()

d = {}

for word in words:
  if word in d:
    d[word]+=1
  else:
    d[word] = 0
  print(d[word], end = " ")
```

Comment: So the same solution I have in my answer, just with different variable names.